# Pivotcache Run Time Error: Type Mismatch in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table using the following code:

```
Sub pivot()
Windows("DATA.xlsx").Activate
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
             SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
             SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

I get an error at

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                 SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                 SourceData:=PRange)
```

It says Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch Error. Can someone help with how to sort this.

Comment: Never noticed this before, but here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create it says this -  "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly."

Answer (score 0):

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
             SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
             SourceData:=PRange.Address(, , , True))
```

This sorted the issue